# login is case sensitive using PGSQL and SQLite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fortify, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

So, I am using Laravel 9x with Jetstream and Inertia/Vue

I am noticing using PGSQL and SQLite the login for email is case sensitive. What is the solution to fix this? I know I am not posting code because it doesnt seem necessary but if there is something you want to see let me know.

I have also heard this does NOT happen with MySQL but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: We do a pre-validation step that lowercases all email addresses. MySQL has a case-insensitive encoding that avoids this.

Comment: @ceejayoz so just for my own thought process, I would need to store in lowercase, then each time a user logs in/resets password I would have to lowercase their email before login correct? Or just move to MySQL which I am not fond of doing

Comment: Yes. I'm not using JetStream, but in our app we adjusted our login `FormRequest`s to [use `prepareForValidation()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) to lowercase it, and put a `User::saving` Eloquent observer to always lowercase the email field right before a save event.

Comment: You ROCK! - Thanks for clarifying this for me. Would you be in a position to share your formRequest code... Ive never done this before and while I am sure I can quickly solve it - I would be curious to see how a working example looks - otherwise thank you for totally clearing my head on this challenge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to Jetstream specifically, but our app uses `FormRequest` classes for the login, password reset, etc. forms.

In each `FormRequest`, we use Laravel's [`prepareForValidation()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method to massage the incoming data.

```
protected function prepareForValidation($attributes) {
    $attributes['email'] = strtolower(trim($attributes['email']));

    return $attributes;
}
```

Additionally, in the User model, we have an [Eloquent mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators) on the email property to ensure updates to this field are normalized:

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['email'] =  trim(strtolower($value));
}
```

(You could also handle this with an Eloquent observer on the `saving` event.)

After changing your app to do this, you'd likely want to run a one-time update to your database to lowercase existing email values in the users table. Forgetting to do this would make it impossible for users with uppercase characters to log in.

Comment: Note that many users expect the case of their email to be preserved. Even though *we* know it doesn't matter, some users will be confused/worried if they enter "MrSmith@gmail.com" and their email is converted to "mrsmith@gmail.com".

Comment: @meagar This is exactly what bothers me about this. I have users who absolutely are convinced your comment is true. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan I've handled this with a "I just sent you an email to the lowercase version."

Comment: I'm also generally bothered by this. I consider mirroring the user's input back to them *as given* a high priority for most use cases. I've offered an alternative using a case-insensitive index in the database itself.

Comment: yep, that was option 1 creating 2 mirrors in the DB. I think just massaging it down with lowercase is going to be the best option for me and then explaining to the user we use lowercase. I am going to test it with a few users and see what happens

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan I will say we've got a work app doing this, with tens of thousands of non-technical users, and I've gotten maybe five questions in support about it

Answer (score 2):

Generally I think it's a good idea to retain user input as the user provided it, and not normalize it (ie converting emails to a uniform case) before saving them to the database. For example, if a user enters `MrSmith@gmail.com` as their email, I prefer to show them `MrSmith@gmail.com` on subsequent pages, and not convert it to `mrsmith@gmail.com` just to make it searchable in the database. Obviously user emails are not case-sensitive, but I think it's mildly rude for software to discard the casing the user prefers to use, and in some cases this could confuse less savvy users who don't understand that emails are case-insensitive.

While this applies to emails, it's *generally* important to be able to search for certain fields in a case-insensitive way, while retaining the exact original values. You wouldn't want to convert the case of somebody's address just to make it searchable, for example.

You can achieve this in Postgres by creating and using case-insensitive indices - more specifically by making an index using a `lower` transform to normalize the casing in the index, but *not* in the column itself.

For example, given a `users` table with an `email` column, you typically create an index using something like this:

```
create unique index users_email_idx on users (email);
```

Instead, you can create the index on `lower(email)`:

```
create unique index users_email_idx on users (lower(email));
```

This allows the values written to the column to retain their original casing. When you insert `MrSmith@gmail.com`, the value retained in the column is `MrSmith@gmail.com` but the value written into the index is `mrsmith@gmail.com`.

There are a few things to note:

First, this enforces uniqueness in a case-insensitive way, so the records `foo@bar.com` and `Foo@Bar.Com` cannot coexist in the database. This is generally both good and necessary for emails, but could cause problems for other types of data.

Secondly, in order to use the index while querying, you need to adjust your query slightly to match the index:

```
select * from users where lower(email) = 'foo@bar.com'; -- uses index
select * from users where email = 'foo@bar.com' -- does not use index
```

The second query is problematic; not only will it miss records where the case doesn't match, it will miss the index entirely and perform a *sequential scan* on your database, which can often be very slow and expensive.

Finally, it's worth explicitly mentioning that you must normalize your search term *before* using it in a query. If a user enters `MrSmith@gmail.com`, you must convert the input to the same case used in the index, or it won't match. This can be done in application code before the string is sent to the database, or you can use `lower` on both sides of the comparison in the database:

```
-- works, database normalizes input:
select * from users where lower(email) = lower('MrSmith@gmail.com')

-- works, application has already normalized input
select * from users where lower(email) = 'mrsmith@gmail.com'

-- No error, but cannot possibly match any records
select * from users where lower(email) = 'MrSmith@gmail.com'
```